# Computation of Network homophily

Tags: r, graph, network-programming, igraph, network-analysis

I am quite confusing about the calculation of network homophily in network analysis. Right now I am compute the homophily by the following function, which have been written and also described by the following URL: http://dappls.umasscreate.net/networks/calculating-network-homophily-part-1/. The goal of this technique is to measure the homophily in a network by their proportion of all edges in a network. My goal is to measure the homophily in a directed network.

#### Function

```
homophily <- function(graph,vertex.attr,attr.val=NULL,prop=T){
  #Assign names as vertex attributes for edgelist output#
  V(graph)$name<-vertex_attr(graph,vertex.attr)

  #Get the basic edgelist#
  ee<-get.data.frame(graph)

  #If not specifying on particular attribute value, get percentage (prop=T)#
  #or count (prop=F) of all nodes tied with matching attribute#
  if(is.null(attr.val)){
    ifelse(prop==T,sum(ee[,1]==ee[,2])/nrow(ee),sum(ee[,1]==ee[,2]))

  #If not null, get proportion (prop=T) or count (prop=F) of#
  #edges among nodes with that particular node attribute value#
  } else {
    ifelse(prop==T,sum(ee[,1]==attr.val & ee[,2]==attr.val)/nrow(ee[ee[,1]==attr.val|ee[,2]==attr.val,]),
           sum(ee[,1]==attr.val & ee[,2]==attr.val))
  }
}
```

#### Sample Data

```
set.seed(5165)
#Random directed graph with 100 nodes and 30% chance of a tie#
gg<-random.graph.game(100,0.3,"gnp",directed=T)

#Randomly assign the node attribute (group numbers 0:3)#
V(gg)$group<-sample(1:5,100,replace=T)
```

#### Output

By applying the function on sample data I receive the following output, which means that 20% of the ties in the network are between actors in the same group. It is also possible to compute the homophily for a specific group in percentage.

```
homophily(graph = abc, vertex.attr = "group")
[1] 0.1971504
```

However I also noticed that the **igraph** package contains as well a homophily method called "*assortativity()*" [described here](http://igraph.org/r/doc/assortativity.html). Executing this function receives completely other results which is based on the assortativity coefficient in a range(-1, 1). The assortativity coefficient is positive is similar vertices (based on some external property) tend to connect to each, and negative otherwise.

```
library(igraph)
assortativity(abc, V(abc)$group, directed=T)
[1] -0.02653782
```

#### Question

So right now I am quite confused, which of these methods is the right one to measure the homophily in a network, because both functions received different results. I also noticed that the igraph method does not support the calculation of particular groups. In my opinion I would rather go with the first one which is self-coded (not sure if there are some mistakes), because the interpretation makes more sense. So my question is, which of the following methods is the right one for measuring the homophily in a network?

Comment: This isn't a specific programming question. What is your definition of "right one"? What measure you use depends on what you want to measure. Rational people may have different definitions of what exactly "homophily" is. Provide the exact definition you want to use.

Comment: Well the definition of homophily in social science is "the tendency of individuals to associate and bond with similar others". In network analysis homophily is described as a process where similar nodes on a particular train are more likely to form ties, which is quite the same as in social science right? I mean if I want to know how heterogeneous or homogenous actors in a network communicate, I would rather choose the first technique. Both techniques measure homophily & receive different results, but right know I can not see any difference (advantage) which one will be used for any reason.

Comment: Your homophily function is calculating Krackhardt's E/I Index: (EL - IL) / (EL + IL). Assortativity is a different measure entirely.

Comment: Okay thanks @knapply, but is it not the same somehow the "same". The definition of Krackhardt's E/I Index is: "The Krackhardt E/I Ratio (or variously the E-I Index) is a social network measure which the relative density of internal connections within a social group compared to the number of connections that group has to the external world"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you clarify "*but is it not the same somehow the "same"* ?

I couldn't access the link initially and misspoke. The `homophily()` function above isn't exactly the same and requires a different interpretation.

Original setup and data:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(5165)
gg <- random.graph.game(100, 0.3, "gnp", directed = TRUE)
V(gg)$group <- sample(1:5, 100, replace = TRUE)
```

Original function:

```
homophily <- function(graph,vertex.attr,attr.val=NULL,prop=T){
  V(graph)$name<-vertex_attr(graph,vertex.attr)
  ee<-get.data.frame(graph)
  if(is.null(attr.val)){
    ifelse(prop==T,sum(ee[,1]==ee[,2])/nrow(ee),sum(ee[,1]==ee[,2]))
  } else {
    ifelse(prop==T,sum(ee[,1]==attr.val & ee[,2]==attr.val)/nrow(ee[ee[,1]==attr.val|ee[,2]==attr.val,]),
           sum(ee[,1]==attr.val & ee[,2]==attr.val))
  }
}
```

Original results:

```
homophily(gg, "group")
#> [1] 0.2017368
```

New function that returns all the relevant details:

```
new_homophily <- function(graph, vertex.attr) {
  V(graph)$name <- vertex_attr(graph, vertex.attr)
  edges <- get.data.frame(graph)
  
  # heterophilous ties where vertices have different `"group"` attributes
  external <- length(which(edges$from != edges$to))
  
  # homophilous ties where vertices have the same `"group"` attributes
  internal <- length(which(edges$from == edges$to))
  
  list(
    n_external = external,
    n_internal = internal,
    prop_external = external / nrow(edges), # proportion of ties that are heterophilous
    prop_internal = internal / nrow(edges), # proportion of ties that are homophilous (the results of your initial function)
    ei_index = (external - internal) / nrow(edges) # (EL - IL) / (EL + IL)
  )
}
```

New results:

```
new_homophily(gg, "group")
#> $n_external
#> [1] 2390
#> 
#> $n_internal
#> [1] 604
#> 
#> $prop_external
#> [1] 0.7982632
#> 
#> $prop_internal
#> [1] 0.2017368        # the results of your initial function ===================
#> 
#> $ei_index
#> [1] 0.5965264
```

Interpreting `$ei_index` should be more straightforward than `$prop_internal`. Values closer to +1 indicate more heterophily while values closer to -1 indicate more homophily.

If that fits your goal, here are some alternative E/I index options:

Michal Bojanowski's routine. It's not on CRAN, but it's available at https://github.com/mbojan/isnar

```
isnar::ei(gg, "group") 
#> [1] 0.5965264
```

Full disclosure: This is my own routine. The package is decidedly unfinished and it's definitely not on CRAN. https://knapply.github.io/homophily/reference/ei_index.html

```
homophily::ei_index(gg, node_attr_name = "group")
#> [1] 0.5965264
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explantation. I only have one question left, right know we compute with the new homophily function the heterphilous and the homophilous ties of the whole group for all attributes right? But is it possible to extend it like for specific attributes, which means only attributes that have a value of 2 in the group vertices right?

Comment: I will definitely have a look at these packages @knapply !